# How do I append an action into a new scene?

Tags: animation, append, actions

Would like to move, link, or append an action onto the same character in a new Blender v2.83 scene.

My teacher moved a kick action I'd created on the first character but I must've not heard him correctly as I tried to move an action to my second character and nothing transferred.

Character 1 - talks to / **kicks** / drags off Character 2
Character 2 - **want to transfer in two actions from other Blender v2.83 scenes**

There is dialogue / sound for desired Character 2 transfer actions - would that also transfer to new scene if actions can be brought into the two character scene?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm unsure if the NLA and Action editor is capable of doing what you're asking but I do all that from the Dopesheet direct. It's just a matter of copying the original's keyframes into the new project after you 'append' a skeletal version of the original.  (No mesh, just the ik targets, the rig, and any 'parents' involved)  If you wish to explore this approach, I can drop an answer to explain.  As for audio, I wonder if that couldn't be included with the append.  Never dabbled with audio outside the VSE and graph editor.

Comment: Thanks Edgel3D!! :D

Comment: I did that last night for a job with identical copies (& rigs) of the same character, and yes it works very well. It's a disciplined process though and one which would require an answer resembling a full blown tutorial of sorts.  Can I ask what your Blender experience level is?  I'm also experimenting with the NLA (again) to see if that will be of use to you but (again) it all fell over very quickly.

Comment: Our class uses v2.83. My experience is intermediate. I'll be graduating in May with an AAS in 2D/3D Animation for TV, Film, & New Media. I really appreciate the help you've given me. I'm putting together my digital demo reel and am using the Blender characters Vincent & Rain for one of the sequences. My teacher brought my Rain roundhouse kick and I wanted to incorporate the verbal actions I'd had for Vincent, but remembered I only lip-synced, so I don't need to crossover, just re-did them :D

Comment: That's great Crystal. :)  Sounds like it's all solved then.  Good luck with your course!